# "Instance has no attribute" using closure inside class (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

my question is about a code with the following structure:

```
class MainClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Func1()
        #some code

    def Func1(self):
        def Func2(self):
            print "test"
            #some more code

        def Func3(self):
            self.Func2()
            #some more code

        self.Func3()

MainClass()
```

When i run something with this structure, python gives the error: "MainClass instance has no attribute 'Func3'". i'm not sure if i misunderstood what i read about closures, or if i just make a mistake at using a closure inside a function.

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Harm

Comment: `self.Func3` does not exists as it's not defined in the class, you can use  `Func3()` in `Func1` instead. same for `self.Func2`

Comment: I feel really dumb now, thanks for the quick answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in your post, `Func2` and `Func3` are not part of `MainClass` class.

You defined functions that can only be seen inside `Func1`, then the `self` argument is not the current instance of the object, it can be rewritten like this

```
def Func1(self):
    def Func2():
        print "test"
        #some more code

    def Func3():
        Func2()
        #some more code

   Func3()
```